# Is "Use Base Internationalization" supported in iOS 5?

Tags: ios, ios5, internationalization, xcode4.5

I have been unable to find a clear answer on this.

In setting up a new project with iOS 5 as the deployment target, and running on an iOS 5 device - I sometimes get the following error. It is not all the time though, and would just like to emliminate incompatiability from the equation.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Base Internationalization" is only available on iOS 6 / OS X 10.8 and later.

If you download the WWDC 2012 session slides (go to https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) then you will find that on page 63 of "Session 232 - Auto Layout by Example.pdf".

Comment: @nomad00: You are welcome. - (I knew that I had seen it somewhere, but it took me some time to find it again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/RolandasRazma/RRBaseInternationalization for iOS5 support.